# how to connecting a variable to .caption in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, variables, button, visual-foxpro, caption

i want to make a variable can be used in .caption, so i can get the value and used it to make something.

last experiment, i use it in foxpro and it can work pretty well.
like this.

[foxpro code mix variable with system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQDCX.jpg)

> tmbl = "command"+alltrim(str(i)) set order to no_room seek
>   (thisform.pageframe1.page1.**&tmbl.**.caption

see the **&tmbl.**?? im using it as a connector to .caption

now im trying to do it in VB.NET. it can not work. i don't know what kind connector must be use in VB.NET. so can somebody please tell what must to use in VB.NET?

Comment: It is the kind of syntactical slight that can only work in a language that is executed by an interpreter.  VB.NET is not such a language, it uses a compiler.  You did not post any VB.NET code, so nobody can show you how to use Reflection to do this.

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: thanks Hans Passant.. the problem already solved

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use controls collection to find the control you want (and even in VFP it is the way to go, instead of abusing the & operator). Say you want to do this for a label, in C# it looks like:

```
var label = this.Controls.OfType<Label>()
      .SingleOrDefault(c => c.Name == "command" + i);

if (label != null)
{
   label.Text = "Whatever";
}
```

Telerik code converter converts this to VB.Net as:

```
Dim label = Me.Controls.OfType(Of Label)().SingleOrDefault(Function(c) c.Name = "command" + i)

If label IsNot Nothing Then
    label.Text = "Whatever"
End If
```

Comment: thanks Cetin Basoz.. that really help me out.. at least i can connect the text appears on my button with field on my table.. thank you very much.. i will attach the code later..